# Acumatica Custom DAC not triggering Business events

Tags: acumatica

Good day

Here is some background:

First created a View to group all a customer's Balances over branches:

```
CREATE VIEW CustomerBalance AS
select CustomerID,  sum(CurrentBal) AS 'CurrentBal'
from ARBalances
group by CustomerID;
```

Thereafter I pulled in the View into a Customization and Acumatica made me this DAC:

```
using System;
using PX.Data;

namespace JVDCustomerCreditLimit
{
  [Serializable]
  [PXCacheName("CustomerBalance")]
  public class CustomerBalance : IBqlTable
  {
    #region CustomerID
    [PXDBInt(IsKey = true)] // Added IsKey not sure if i should have...
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Customer ID")]
    public virtual int? CustomerID { get; set; }
    public abstract class customerID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<customerID> { }
    #endregion

    #region CurrentBal
    [PXDBDecimal()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Current Bal")]
    public virtual Decimal? CurrentBal { get; set; }
    public abstract class currentBal : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<currentBal> { }
    #endregion
  }
}
```

With the above, I made a GI that links in the customer master for the credit limit

Here is the issue:

I made a Business event that looks for changes on the GI.
The Business event fires when I update the Credit limit(BAccount) but not if CurrentBalDAC(View) changed.

What did I miss on the DAC's code so that the business event will fire if there is a change?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is that you are using a SQL view to drive data into the GI. Changes are not going to be detected as it will be other entities that are receiving the actual change.

Comment: Hi Robert, I was thinking the same. Do you know of an attribute that one can use on the DAC to tell Acumatica to look/check for changes?

Comment: Im not 100% sure it will work but you could look into a PXProjection that would aggregate the values. If that leads nowhere you might be able to tie in something on the subsidiary detail that would aggregate a value and post it the record you want to wire the GI into. That should in turn do a proper trigger to get your notification out. I am curious to see how this unfolds and how it gets solved in the end.